# How can I split a 2D array into an array with unique values and a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to split a 2D array into a specific format and can't figure out the last step. A sample of my data is structured as follows:

```
# Original Data
fileListCode = [['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_057'], 
                ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_053'], 
                ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_054'],
                ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_001'], 
                ['Seq98.xls', 'D25034_002'], 
                ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_003']]
```

I am trying to split it up so that it looks like this:

```
# split into [['Seq3.xls', {'B08524_057':1,'B08524_053':2, 'B08524_054':3},
#             ['Seq98.xls',{'B25034_001':1,'D25034_002':2, 'B25034_003':3}]
```

The dictionary keys 1,2,3 are based on the original position of the entry, starting from the first time that the filename appears. To do this, I've first made an array to get all the unique file names (anything that is `.xls` is a filename)

```
tmpFileList = []
tmpCodeList = []
arrayListDict = []

# store unique filelist in a tempprary array:
for i in range( len(fileListCode)):
    if fileListCode[i][0] not in tmpFileList:
        tmpFileList.append( fileListCode[i][0]  )
```

However, I'm struggling with the next step. I can't figure out a good way of pulling out the codenames (`B08524_052` for example), and converting them into a dictionary with an index based on their position.

```
# make array to store filelist, and codes with dictionary values
for i in range( len(tmpFileList)):
    arrayListDict.append([tmpFileList[i], {}])
```

This code just produces `[['Seq3.xls', {}], ['Seq98.xls', {}]]` ; I'm not sure whether I should first produce the structure and then try and add the code and dictionary values in, or whether there is a better way.

--
EDIT: I just made sample a little more clear by changing the values in `fileListCode`

Comment: You should describe more what are the numbers 1, 2, 3 that are values in {'B08524_052':1,'B08524_053':2, 'B08524_054':3} for exemple.

Comment: Thank you. So, the numbers 1,2,3 are indexes of appearance in the group of a certain file name. BTW, be aware that 1,2,3 are not keys of dictionary, but values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With, itertools.groupby this process will be much simplier:

```
>>> key = operator.itemgetter(0)
>>> grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(fileListCode, key=key), key=key)
>>> [(i, {k[1]: n for n, k in enumerate(j, 1)}) for i, j in grouped]
[('Seq3.xls', {'B08524_052': 1, 'B08524_053': 2, 'B08524_054': 3}),
 ('Seq98.xls', {'B25034_001': 1, 'B25034_002': 2, 'B25034_003': 3})]
```

For old Python versions:

```
>>> [(i, dict((k[1], n) for n, k in enumerate(j, 1))) for i, j in grouped]
[('Seq3.xls', {'B08524_052': 1, 'B08524_053': 2, 'B08524_054': 3}),
 ('Seq98.xls', {'B25034_001': 1, 'B25034_002': 2, 'B25034_003': 3})]
```

But I think using dict would be better:

```
>>> {i: {k[1]: n for n, k in enumerate(j, 1)} for i, j in grouped}
{'Seq3.xls': {'B08524_052': 1, 'B08524_053': 2, 'B08524_054': 3},
 'Seq98.xls': {'B25034_001': 1, 'B25034_002': 2, 'B25034_003': 3}}
```

Comment: wow. I'm just trying to understand this; as the position of the code `B....` is important, and the code changes (e.g. `C123...`), will this affect what the dictionary entry is?

Comment: Is it possible to use this syntax in Python 2.6.5? It ran fine using python 32, but on 2.6.5 it does not work and I don't understand it well enough to figure out what to change.

Comment: Dictionary comprehension came with Python 2.7. But you can convert it to a generator expression or list comprehension and manually call dict() to it, for example: `dict((k[1], n) for n, k in enumerate(j, 1))`

Comment: I'm having problems with this line: `[(i, {k[1]: n for n, k in enumerate(j, 1)}) for i, j in grouped]` (I really prefer the list/dict combination.
`

Comment: @celenius Writing the line as follows makes it more understandable: ``[(duo0, {duo[1]: pos for pos, duo in enumerate(gr_of_duos, start=1)}) for duo0, gr_of_duos in grouped]``

Answer (score 2):

You've confused lists and dictonaries.

It would make far more sense to do something more like this:

```
file_list_code = [['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_052'],
                  ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_053'],                  
                  ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_054'],                 
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_001'],                  
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_002'],                  
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_003']] 

file_codes = {}
for name, code in file_list_code:
    if name not in file_codes:
        file_codes[name] = []
    file_codes[name].append(code)
```

This yields:

```
{'Seq3.xls': ['B08524_052', 'B08524_053', 'B08524_054'], 
'Seq98.xls': ['B25034_001', 'B25034_002', 'B25034_003']}
```

This could be further simplifed by using a defaultdict. It's arguably overkill for something this simple, but it's good to know about. Here's an example:

```
import collections

file_list_code = [['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_052'],
                  ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_053'],                  
                  ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_054'],                 
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_001'],                  
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_002'],                  
                  ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_003']] 

file_codes = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, code in file_list_code:
    file_codes[name].append(code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do still need to have the second piece in a dictionary format for looking up later.

Comment: @celenius - Your dictonary values appear to just be indicies... A list is much simpler in that case and accomplishes exactly the same thing. (e.g. `file_codes[filename].index('B25034_002')`).

Comment: I need to get the position of the codes later though and as the lists are large I thought a dictionary would be best.

Comment: @celenius - Better is relative. A list stores the order inherently, but finding the index within the list is a linear-time operation. Finding the value for a given dictionary key will be faster (constant-time), but a dictionary will take up more memory and is more complex to construct. Personally, I'd stick with a list for this unless there is a really good reason not to. Is calling `somelist.index(...)` actually a bottleneck? Of course, it's partly personal taste, as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
fileListCode = [['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_052'],
                ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_053'],
                ['Seq3.xls', 'B08524_054'],
                ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_001'],
                ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_002'],
                ['Seq98.xls', 'B25034_003']]

dico = {}
li = []
for a,b in fileListCode:

    if a in dico:
        li[dico[a]][1][b] = len( li[dico[a]][1] ) + 1


    else:
        dico[a] = len(li)
        li.append([a,{b:1}])


print '\n'.join(map(str,li))
```